# WebAssemblyでWindowsAPIを呼ぶことは可能でしょうか？

Tags: javascript, webassembly

WebAssemblyについて参考にしたサイトはこちらです。
http://qiita.com/pnlybubbles/items/0410e978afce647cf0b6

上記サイトはC++のコードを実行しているだけですが、このC++コードでWindowsAPIを呼ぶことは可能なのでしょうか？
また、いずれ可能になる予定や予兆はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub の WebAssembly のところを見てみると、[Portability / API](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/Portability.md#api) の節で、どんな API が利用できるかが書いてあります。ざっと訳すと

> WebAssembly 自体は API を定義せず、実行環境で定義されたものを import する機能だけを提供。ウェブの環境の API は [Web Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Web_Platform) で定義された Web API。ウェブ以外の環境では、どんな API を実装してもよい。

ということなので、ブラウザから Windows API を直に呼べるようになることは、ないでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。今のところは無理そうですね。
今後も難しそうですが。